# How can extract rank of particular row from result set

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
with baseQuery as(
                  select id,
                  (select sum(calories) from dailytable where user_id in (select user_id from group_members where group_id=132 and status = 'accepted' and user_id=users.id)) as total_calories
                  from users where id in (select user_id from group_members where group_id=132 and status='accepted'))
                  select *,dense_rank() over(order by total_calories desc nulls last) as rank
from baseQuery;
```

This is my Query and Output is as below.

```
    id    total_calorie         rank
    121   2516.054250000001     1
    25    897.0234000000002     2
    120   784.13784             3
```

I want to get only rank of user id 120 but when I am putting where condition on above query It is returning rank as 1 instead of 3.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add another CTE after the first:

```
with 
baseQuery as 
(
    select id, (select sum(calories) from dailytable where user_id in (select user_id from group_members where group_id=132 and status = 'accepted' and user_id=users.id)) as total_calories
    from users where id in (select user_id from group_members where group_id=132 and status='accepted')
), 
ranked_query as 
(
    select *,dense_rank() over(order by total_calories desc nulls last) as rank
    from baseQuery
)
select * from ranked_query where id = 120;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, It works as per my requirement.

Comment: You could probably simplify the query a bit too as you have a repeating condition filtering the user id in two places, but as the inner one is correlated to the outer at least one of them is redundant and could be removed.